# What is Promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Before posing this question I have researched lots of related Promise on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Can you please explain to me in a simple word like

1. What is Promise?
2. How and when to use?
3. Any simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting MDN:

> A Promise is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. **This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.**
>
> Essentially, a promise is a returned object to which you attach callbacks, instead of passing callbacks into a function.

Basically, if you have some synchronous code (eg. `alert()`), and you needed to use an asynchronous function (eg. `setTimeout()`), you could use a promise (as shown on the first example).

Here is the example:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

console.log(promise1);
// expected output: [object Promise]
```

Use it to combine synchronous code with asynchronous code.

Answer (score -3):

It is very simple thing. Promise is good for async operation. You can take example of Q.js and Promise.js.